# How to trigger a moment of animateCamera zoom end 'only'?

Tags: google-maps, triggers, ontouchlistener

I can catch this moment by using a listener:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(destLatLng, 15));

 map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    //here some code...
                }
            });
```

The problem is this method will trigger all moments of user map touching, and i don't want it.

I want to trigger ONLY the moment after map does its zoom *animation* towards the end and the animation stops. By the way where you touch the map, map usually doesn't produce any animation.

So, even I might say any situation where map starts some zoom animation and finishes it, I want a listener. But only there!

(I could put some flag at any user touch event and check in *onCameraChange* some value, but... is there a normal solution?)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by custom controls. Create your own controls to handle interaction with the user. Displays some UI to the user, and handles interaction with either the user or the map, usually through an event handler. Google Maps Javascript API provides a cross-browser event handling method  ['addDomListener()'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?utm_source=welovemaspdevelopers&utm_campaign=stackoverflow#CustomEvents)
which handles most of the browser's supported  [DOM events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events).

You specify a  [control's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?utm_source=welovemaspdevelopers&utm_campaign=stackoverflow#ControlOptions) presentation when you create your map through fields within the map's MapOptions object.

Comment: only Javascript method? I need Java (i made some mistake putting 'jquery-animate' tag, it's removed).